# What's wrong with the expression?

Tags: errors, warnings

```
P(S_t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t S_t} \sigma} e^\left [ -\frac{1}{2t} \left ( \frac{\log \left ( \frac{St}{S_0} \right ) - \mu t }{\sigma} \right ) ^2 \right ]
```

Log:

```
Missing { inserted. ...frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t S_t} \sigma} e^\left
Missing } inserted. ... ) - \mu t }{\sigma} \right ) ^2 \right ]$
Overfull \hbox (7.07501pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 1237) in paragraph
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
```

Answer (score 7):

I took the opportunity to improve your expression: the internal parentheses are unnecessary, and we can fine-tune the size of delimiters. Altenatively, we can use `\exp` and the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\[ P(S_t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t S_t} \sigma} e^{-\frac{1}{2t}\Bigl( \frac{\log \frac{St}{S_0} - \mu t }{\sigma} \Bigr)^2} \]%

May be better-looking, with \verb+\mfrac+ (from \texttt{nccmath}): 
\[ P(S_t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t S_t} \sigma}\exp{\Biggl [ -\mfrac{1}{2t} \Bigl( \mfrac{\log \frac{St}{S_0} - \mu t }{\sigma} \Bigr) ^2 \Biggr]} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you might add `exp()` notation for long exponents.

Comment: You're perfectly right.  I'll add it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Bernard, first time I see `heuristica`. What is purpose of this package? Since `e` is not variable, what you think about `\mathrm{e}^{....}`?

Comment: @Zarko: Sorry, I took an old file of mine as a basis. `Heuristica` is a free extension to `Adobe Utopia` (hence it goes well  with `fourier`), which provides true smallcaps, cyrillic glyphs, inferior and superior numbers. Actually it is still better to use `Erewhon`, that extends (and also modifies Heuristica). Both exist in opentype and type1 formats. As for `e`, I didn't want to go against the O.P.'s choice. Personally,  I use what you suggest.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for above information. I was not aware for this font extension. Good to know this, since I usually use fouriernc and can becomes handy.

Comment: There's no need for the outer brackets in the exponent in `e^[...]`.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing braces around the exponent. So TeX is trying to write `e` to the power of left bracket.

And TeX is different than Python etc. Don't use spurious whitespaces. You will get strange results once in a while and will drive you crazy while debugging.

Comment: By “spurious whitespaces” do you mean spaces in, e.g., `\left (` or `\right ]`? If you are referring to whitespace in math mode… I have to disagree. The code is many many times more readable with whitespace in between. I don't know why people try to save strokes there, making the math mode almost impossible to read `$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_D(f(x)+g'(x))\,dx=3+e^{2}-2(1*M)+A$` and `$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_D (f(x) + g'(x)) \d x = 3 + e^{2} - 2(1*M) + A$` (bad example, just written now in less than twenty seconds).

Comment: @Manuel I can read your comment more easier than in the question. You have to parse things in a group context putting extra effort on your eyes. You can of course group things but `\left [` is just OCD in my opinion. You have to reduce the load on the reader not discipline them. Also if you make this into habit and use everywhere you will spend time removing them and seeing whether it is the space that is causing the problem rendering it useless.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your last comment :) I mean I think it's just much more readable the code which has “similar” spacing to the output (that is, spaces around relations and binary operations mostly). In the case of `\left [` I definitely think that space is wrong, `\left[` much better. But for instance `(A+B)=-c+e^2`, I would prefer `(A + B) = -c + e^2`. That's all I said. I don't understand what you mean about putting extra effort on your eyes, about discipline the reader (or the load). And I don't see what occasions you may have problems with those spaces.

Comment: Thinking about whether to put space or not while typing for `(A + B) = -c + e^2` is, as you know well to avoid `(A + B) = - c + e ^2` is for me pretty wrong. That's what I meant by grouping *should I group `-c` or not*. Your first comment and last is not in the same tone. Now you are *preferring* some of the spaces and avoiding some. That's what I meant in mine. I also put spaces where I **know** it won't be a problem. But OP's version is excessive and unreadable. That's what I said in essence above.

Comment: Let me chip in just to say this should be done automatically by the editor.

Answer (score 6):

do you want this equation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
 P(S_t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t S_t} \sigma} 
  \mathrm{e}^{\left [ -\frac{1}{2t} \left ( \frac{\log 
     \left ( \frac{St}{S_0} \right ) - 
        \mu t }{\sigma} \right ) ^2 \right]} 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no need for the outer brackets in the exponent in `e^[...]`.

Comment: it doesn't hurt ...

Answer (score 5):

I would tweak your formula as follows:

- Use `\exp[...]` instead of `e^{...}` notation
- Don't use `\left` and `\right` to autosize the parentheses; use `\big` and `\bigg` instead.
- Fine-tune the position of the "2" exponent, and add a thinspace before the final closing square bracket.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
P(S_t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t S_t} \,\sigma} 
\exp\biggl[ -\frac{1}{2t} \biggl( 
\frac{\log \bigl ( \frac{St}{S_0} \bigr ) - \mu t }{\sigma} 
\biggr)^{\!\!2}\, \biggr]
\]

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: @Herbert has asked, in a follow-up comment, why `\left` and `\right` shouldn't be used for this formula. The reason is that the resulting parentheses are too large, typographically speaking, and end up visually dominating the remaining material. The following screenshot shows the consequence of auto-sizing the parentheses, as well as of not adjusting the spacing before and after the `2` exponent term.

[image]

Comment: why shouldn't one use `\left ... \right`?

Comment: @Herbert - I've posted an addendum to demonstrate that letting the parentheses be auto-sized via `\left` and `\right` makes them become visually dominant.

Comment: from my point of view the parentheses with `\big` are too small

Comment: @Herbert - I guess we can agree to disagree... :-)

Answer (score 0):

As there are usually many ways to obtain results in LaTeX, this is yet another.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
P(S_{t}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t S_{t}} \, \sigma} \cdot \exp{\left[    - \frac{\left( \log \left( \frac{S t}{S_{0}} \right) - \mu t \right)^{2}}{2 \, t \, \sigma^{2}} \right]}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no need for the outer brackets in the exponent in `e^[...]`.

Comment: Also why `align`?

Comment: As to the two comments: Svend personal preference in keeping all things enclosed; Percusse use of too many multi-line expressions makes it habbit.